# Ошибка при обновлении плагина WordPress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

При обновлении Akismet Anti-Spam произошла ошибка: Загрузка не удалась. Предоставлен неверный URL.

**Warning:** Произошла непредвиденная ошибка. Возможно, что-то не так с сайтом WordPress.org или с настройками вашего сервера. Если проблема не решится, обратитесь на форумы поддержки. (Не удалось установить защищённое соединение с WordPress.org. Пожалуйста, свяжитесь с администратором сервера.) in **W:\domains\wordpress\wp-includes\update.php** on line **388**

**Warning:** Произошла непредвиденная ошибка. Возможно, что-то не так с сайтом WordPress.org или с настройками вашего сервера. Если проблема не решится, обратитесь на форумы поддержки. (Не удалось установить защищённое соединение с WordPress.org. Пожалуйста, свяжитесь с администратором сервера.) in **W:\domains\wordpress\wp-includes\update.php** on line **577**

Все обновления завершены.

Comment: Видимо, временный сбой на wp.org. Встречал такое тоже.

Comment: Настрой, а лучше выкинь локальный недосервер и используй нормальный хостинг.

Answer (score 0):

Ни одно из вышеописанных  решении не только не помогли в моем случае ,а не имеют отношение к проблеме . зато я подозревая, что, что-то не так с файлом htacces взял и удалил (если решайте поступать также , сделайте копию) из папки public html и все заработало как масло и мёд. возьмите на заметку, может кому то пригодится . речь идет о хостинге джустхост , о других хостингах ничего не могу сказать